# calculating square root for implementating a fixed point function

Tags: c++, fixed-point, square-root

i am trying to find the square root of a fixed point and i used the following Calculation to find an approximation of the square root using an integer algorithm. The algorithm is described in Wikipedia: 
 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots

```
uint32_t SquareRoot(uint32_t a_nInput)
{
    uint32_t op  = a_nInput;
    uint32_t res = 0;
    uint32_t one = 1uL << 30; // The second-to-top bit is set: use 1u << 14 for uint16_t type; use 1uL<<30 for uint32_t type


    // "one" starts at the highest power of four <= than the argument.
    while (one > op)
    {
        one >>= 2;
    }

    while (one != 0)
    {
        if (op >= res + one)
        {
            op = op - (res + one);
            res = res +  2 * one;
        }
        res >>= 1;
        one >>= 2;
    }
    return res;
}
```

but i am unable to follow whats happening in the code what does the comment `// "one" starts at the highest power of four <= than the argument.` exactly means. Can someone please hint me whats happening in the code to calculate the square root of the argument  `a_nInput`

Thanks much

Comment: `n <<= a` is equivalent to `n *= 2^a` or `n = n * 2^a` where `2^a` is the ath power of 2 and `n >>= a` is equivalent to `n /= 2^a` or `n = n / 2^a` where, again, `2^a` is the ath power of 2.

Comment: here ´one >>= 2;´ so we need to return ´one´ or ´res´ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note how `one` is initialized.

```
uint32_t one = 1uL << 30;
```

That's 2<sup>30</sup>, or `1073741824`.  Which is also 4<sup>15</sup>.

This line:

```
    one >>= 2;
```

Is equivalent to

```
    one = one / 4;
```

So the pseudocode for what's happening is:

- `one` = 4<sup>15</sup>
- if `one` is more than `a_nInput`

  - `one` = 4<sup>14</sup>
- if `one` is still more than `a_nInput`

  - `one` = 4<sup>13</sup>
- (and so on...)

Eventually, `one` will **not** be more than `a_nInput`.

```
// "one" starts at the highest power of four less than or equal to a_nInput
```

Comment: I guess OP is asking why  "one" should start at the highest power of four <= than the argument."